# securing api using basic authentication and jwt token

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, basic-authentication

Currently my apis are secured using basic authentication. i would like to jwt token authentication to my code. but i would like my apis to be secured by both mechanism together. reason is so that client do not need to make change in their implementation.is there a way to do it

Comment: why you need JWT on top of basic authentication ? Also do you need both basic authentication and JWT for same API ?

Comment: yeah i mean jwt and basic authentication together for the same api. if client use basic auth, they should go the basicauth filter and if the client uses the jwt token then they should go to jwt filter

Comment: i was able to solve the issue with using Order on WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor and using RequestMatcher